# Apache Zeppelin AD/LDAP Realm

Tags: java, shiro, apache-zeppelin

We have successfully got our shiro.ini "activeDirectoryRealm" authentication working with our companies Active Directory, but for some reason we cannot get our principal's roles to populate properly once the authentication mechanism is completed.

Here is an example of our shiro.ini file:

```
[main]
activeDirectoryRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.server.ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm
activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername = CN=user,OU=FOO,DC=FOOINC,DC=COM
activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword = FOOPASS
activeDirectoryRealm.searchBase = DC=FOOINC,DC=COM
activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldap://ldaps.fooinc.com
activeDirectoryRealm.groupRolesMap = "CN=Foo Users":"foo"
activeDirectoryRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = true

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 600000 
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login 
securityManager.realms = $activeDirectoryRealm 

[roles]
foo = *

[urls]
/api/version = authc
/** = authc
```

Now the dilemma is once we successfully log into Zeppelin I get the following log entry:

```
LoginRestApi.java[postLogin]:111) - {"status":"OK","message":"","body":{"principal":"fooinc\\user","ticket":"24e28a47-d852-460e-9690-6196e094469f","roles":"[]"}}
```

Also what I am confused on is why is the "DefaultLdapContextFactory.java" under the 'realm/ldap' being called to initialize LDAP instead of "ActiveDirectoryRealm.java" under the 'realm/activedirectory'?

Please let me know if you need any further information to help with this issue.

Comment: The connection to your AD server is made using the protocol: LDAP.  As for why you are not getting your groups back could be a few things.  I personally have not experience with Zepplin.  But a couple things to try:

Turn up the logging (both `org.apache.shiro` and for `org.apache.zeppelin.server.ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm`)

Run the queries against your server manually, and see if you are seeing the results you expect.

Do you have an atypical AD structure?

Comment: I've turned logging to debug mode and nothing seems out of the ordinary. Our enterprise AD is pretty massive and speaking with the AD team it might be something on their end. So I'm investigating how to use SAML or OAUTH instead